# How to include multiple packages with one statement in Ada?

Tags: package, ada

I wrote a library in Ada and I would like for the client to only need to include one package into their code. Something like:

```
with all_packages;
```

That will include all the packages useful for the client. I wrote the library with one package for each tagged type to keep things simple and easy to read.

How do I give the library user the possibility to include all packages with only one statement?

Comment: There is a pathological way to do this. Embed all your packages as nested packages within a single collective one that the client can then 'with'.  This makes your client then dependent on any change to any of the packages, whether it concerns them or no. Should I ever have to be a client of such an atrocity I would hunt you down and punch you in the neck.  Just sayin'...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

You did well by encapsulating each tagged type in its own package, that's the approach recommended for object-oriented programming in Ada.

Client code then simply 'withs' just those packages it needs.

Comment: Technically `with Ada, Ada.Numerics, Ada.Numerics, Ada.Strings.Fixed;` is one statement.

Comment: There's probably a good reason for not supporting this, but I could not find a reference. I guess it is related to the [Beaujolais](http://www.adapower.com/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=FAQ&CID=357) and [Ripple](http://www.adapower.com/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=FAQ&CID=358) effects.